# Unable to update MAAS nodes, apt-get update fails with error 503

Tags: apt, maas

Not sure it is correlated but I have just updated to MAAS 1.9 and since tow days, apt-get update fails on all MAAS nodes. I have other non MAAS nodes and they work fine although they use a local repository rather than archive.ubuntu.com.

Below the output of apt-get update.

```
ubuntu@machine:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://qgis.org trusty InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en [762 kB]
Hit http://qgis.org trusty/main Sources
Hit http://qgis.org trusty/main amd64 Packages
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en [102 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en [3,457 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en [4,089 kB]
Ign http://qgis.org trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://qgis.org trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [422 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [6,863 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [222 kB]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages 503  Service Unavailable
Fetched 5,607 kB in 20s (274 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages 503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages 503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages 503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

As one can see there seem to be an issue in the last url referred with the "//", which comes form the /etc/apt/sources.list to but this was not a problem before as updates worked fine and third parties ppa install worked too without problem.

Below the sources.list file.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu  trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu  trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu  trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
```

Note that I am able to see the url that fails with wget except that with "Packages.gz" it works but not with "Packages" (and works with //).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something got broken with the MAAS 1.9 upgrade and proxy for apt. Commenting the proxy settings line in 90curtin-aptproxy did the trick.

```
ubuntu@machine:/etc/apt/apt.conf.d$ more 90curtin-aptproxy
#Acquire::HTTP::Proxy "http://<MAAS_IP>:8000/";
```

I am now able to run apt-get update and upgrade the MAAS nodes as needed. Probably a bug a configuration has not changed in MAAS and is default.